# Any issues with wrapping Modernizr or Respond.js in a LT IE 9 conditional comment?

Tags: modernizr, conditional-comments, respond.js

I'm looking to block the loading of Modernizr and Respond.js from browsers other than IE 8 and below. Since these are render blocking javascript, I'm doing this to optimize my page speed as much as possible. I'm not too concerned about other older browsers, since IE 8 and below always seem to hang on like a sticky booger. I'm only using Modernizr and Respond.js so IE 8 and below can support the use of the HTML selectors I'm using, and media queries. Since the CSS is mobile first, I'd like to have the desktop layout look reasonable on IE 8, thus the Respond.js.

Anyway, is this use of conditional comments an Ok approach? Is there a better way? By just focussing on IE8 and below, am I neglecting any other older version of a popular browser. I don't think so, but I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've probably confirmed by now. This is precisely how I've solved the problem on my pages. I feel pretty confident based on this post: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/issues/223. Apparently greater than IE10 no longer supports conditionals but you probably don't need them for those browsers anyway.